# Delete duplicates from given table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-delete

I have a table named "TABLE1" having few columns

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 ( PAN_ID VARCHAR2(2)      NOT NULL, 
                      CODE VARCHAR2(3)      NULL, 
                      FROM_DT VARCHAR2(10)  NULL, 
                      FROM_TM VARCHAR2(8)   NULL, 
                      IMP_DT TIMESTAMP(3)   NULL );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX INDEX1 ON TABLE1(PAN_ID, IMP_DT);
CREATE INDEX INDEX2 ON TABLE1(PAN_ID);
```

---

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('A1', 'ABC', '2021-07-12', '12:32:02', '09-AUG-21 12.00.00.000000000AM'); 
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('A1', 'ABC', '2021-07-12', '12:32:02', '');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('B1', 'BCD', '2021-07-12', '12:32:01', '09-AUG-21 12.00.00.000000000AM');  
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('B1', 'BCD', '2021-07-12', '12:32:01', ''); 
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('C1', 'CDE', '2021-07-12', '12:31:58', '09-AUG-21 12.00.00.000000000AM');
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES('C1', 'CDE', '2021-07-12', '12:31:58', '');
```

---

I have nearly 400 duplicates but I have presented you the sample rows.

I want to delete the duplicates present in TABLE1. I have used below query to delete duplicates but not able to delete the duplicates:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1 T1 WHERE ROWID IN 
(
   SELECT CID FROM 
                 (
                    SELECT MAX(ROWID) AS CID FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY PAN_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                  )
);
```

The above one is used in Oracle SQL developer application. I want to delete the rows having duplicates...for example in above you can see 3 PAN_ID's has repeated 2 times...Whatever the PAN_ID's present more than once....I want to delete those entries...i.e resultant table should be empty according to above sample input rows...If there is only 1 row for each PAN_ID, then we shouldn't delete those rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with these

```
DELETE 
FROM 
    TABLE1 T1 
WHERE 
    ROWID > (
        SELECT 
            MIN(ROWID) 
        FROM  TABLE1 T2
        WHERE 
            T1.PAN_ID =T2.PAN_ID
        );
```

Comment: While deleting it is saying INDEX2 is in unusable state - So I tried to drop the index2 by executing below query : BEGIN    DROP INDEX INDEX2; COMMIT; END;/   It is showing error as "begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod
null pragma raise return select update while with
<an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
<a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock
insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall
merge pipe purge"

Comment: try to rebuild the concerned index